# Returning pointer to local variable sorted merge

Tags: c, algorithm, merge, linked-list, mergesort

In class I learned not to return pointers to local variables. In this function I found, sorted merge, it seems to return a pointer to a node. How come this is okay?

```
struct node *SortedMerge(struct node *a, struct node *b) { 
    struct node dummy; // a dummy first node to hang the result on
    
    struct node *tail = &dummy; // Points to the last result node --
                                // so tail->next is the place to add
                                // new nodes to the result.
    dummy.next = NULL;

    while (1) {
        if (a == NULL) { // if either list runs out, use the other list
            tail->next = b;
            break;
        } else
        if (b == NULL) {
            tail->next = a;
            break;
        }
        if (a->data <= b->data) {
            MoveNode(&(tail->next), &a);
        } else {
            MoveNode(&(tail->next), &b);
        }
        tail = tail->next;
    } //end while
    return (dummy.next);
}

void MoveNode(struct node **destRef, struct node **sourceRef) {
    struct node *newNode = *sourceRef;  // the front source node
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    *sourceRef = newNode->next;  // Advance the source pointer
    newNode->next = *destRef;    // Link the old dest off the new node
    *destRef = newNode;          // Move dest to point to the new node
}
```

Comment: It's not returning a pointer to a local variable. it's returning `dummy.next`, which is a pointer that came from the caller.

Comment: Does `dummy.next` ever point to a local variable? It doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: @Kevin Isn't dummy created in the function which means it is local?

Comment: `dummy` is local, and if you returned `&dummy` it would be a problem.  But `dummy.next` is a pointer that does not point to a local variable, so it is fine to use as a return value.

Comment: @RoshanSamarawickrema the problem comes when you return a pointer that points to a local variable. The pointer itself being local isn't a problem.

Comment: Just a comment, for C or C++, a pointer to pointer to node could have been used instead of a dummy node, but in the case of Java, which doesn't have generic pointers, a dummy node is typically used, so the code is a bit more generic.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that `dummy` is a local variable, and you should be concerned that a pointer to this local does not get returned.  However, notice that what is returned is `dummy.next`, which is a pointer that could point to anything, so it's not forced to point to anything local.

Looking at the logic flow, `dummy.next` ends up pointing to either `NULL`, something related to input parameter `a`, or something related to input parameter `b`.  That is, the returned pointer points to something related to the arguments, not the local structure.

By the way, the function's author was trying to help point that out by calling the local *`dummy`*.  This is supposed to connote that it is not a *real* node (hence a *dummy*) that serves only as a convenient mechanism to process the function's logic and not a persistent node.

Answer (score 0):

The function does not return a pointer to a local object, it returns the value of a local object `dummy.next`, a pointer initialized to `NULL` and set to either `a` or `b` during first iteration of the loop, depending on the values of `a`, `b` and the comparison of `a->data` and `b->data` if neither `a` nor `b` is a null argument.

The function uses a *dummy* list node to avoid making a special case of the first iteration. Here is a simpler version that uses a double pointer for the same purpose:

```
struct node *SortedMerge(struct node *a, struct node *b) {
    struct node *head = NULL;    // the head of the merged list.
    struct node **link = &head;  // pointer to the link to attach the next node to

    for (;;) {
        if (a == NULL) { // if either list runs out, use the other list
            *link = b;
            break;
        } else
        if (b == NULL) {
            *link = a;
            break;
        }
        if (a->data <= b->data) {
            *link = a;
            link = &a->next;
            a = a->next;
        } else {
            *link = b;
            link = &b->next;
            b = b->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Here is a longer but arguably more readable version without double pointers:

```
struct node *SortedMerge(struct node *a, struct node *b) {
    struct node *head;    // the head of the merged list.
    struct node *tail;    // the tail node of the merged list.

    if (a == NULL)
        return b;
    if (b == NULL)
        return a;
    if (a->data <= b->data) {
        tail = head = a;
        a = a->next;
    } else {
        tail = head = b;
        b = b->next;
    }
    for (;;) {
        if (a == NULL) { // if either list runs out, use the other list
            tail->next = b;
            break;
        } else
        if (b == NULL) {
            tail->next = a;
            break;
        }
        if (a->data <= b->data) {
            tail = tail->next = a;
            a = a->next;
        } else {
            tail = tail->next = b;
            b = b->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```